# spring social Twitter update status not giving id_str

Tags: java, spring, twitter, spring-social-twitter

I am using spring social twitter for my project.  I am trying to make tweet favorite, for that I need **id_str** = "your tweet id".  But the problem is when I do update status using spring social it's return **id** = "" but not **id_str**.  I seen that it's returning [Tweet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/Tweet.html) class.  In that class there is no such field like **id_str**.  So my question is how can I get **id_str**.

NOTE : id and id_str are note same.  it's returning different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` and `id_str` **should** be the same.  `id_str` is there because some platforms have difficulty handling very large integers.

You should use `getId()` and then cast the long into a string.

Comment: Thanks Terence.
I already check that before.  Even if you look at twitter console https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console . In this try to update status it's will give both id and id_str both which are different.

Answer (score 0):

The id_str is available in the extraData map:

twitterProfile.getExtraData().get("id_str")